# MySQL database as table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a table with PHP, but it won't work...
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Table with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$dblink=mysqli_connect('IP','username','password');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Error: Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_select_db($dblink,'database');

$abfrage='$dblink,"SELECT * FROM database"';
$ergebnis='mysqli_query($abfrage)';
?>

<table width="1000" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<th>var1</th>
<th>var2</th>
<th>var3</th>
</tr>
```

The error is somewhere here

```
<?php

while($row='mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis)'){
echo '<tr>'."\r\n";

echo '<td>'.$row->var1.'</td>'."\r\n";
echo '<td>'.$row->var2.'</td>'."\r\n";
echo '<td>'.$row->var3.'</td>'."\r\n";

echo '<tr>'."\r\n";
}

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

The errors are:

> **Notice:** Trying to get property 'var1' of non-object in (Path) on line xx
>
> **Notice:** Trying to get property 'var2' of non-object in (Path) on line xx
>
> **Notice:** Trying to get property 'var3' of non-object in (Path) on line xx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: do you have a table named `database` ?

Comment: `$row` is a *string*, it doesn't have any properties.  You are randomly enclosing code in quotes, which makes it a string.  You're doing this in several places.

Comment: if you are create table using query then  where is you create table query.  like  $query = CREATE TABLE table_name (
                column1 datatype,
                column2 datatype,
                column3 datatype,
                ....
    );  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ergebnis='mysqli_query($abfrage)';`
and `$row='mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis)'` should not be quoted, since now you're not querying the database, but just declaring strings.

It should be `$ergebnis=mysqli_query($dblink, $abfrage);`
and `$row=mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis)`. Also `$abfrage='$dblink,"SELECT * FROM database"'` should be `$abfrage="SELECT * FROM table_name"` where `table_name` is the name of the table you want to query.

An example on how to query a database using php can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-object-examples).

Comment: Than the errors are:
    **Warning:**  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in "Path" on line xx
    **Warning:** mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in "Path" on line xx

Comment: Im sorry, I missed a few more problems with your code. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your answer. Most of the errors are fixed now but one is still there. It's the line with the $row variable. I post the error here:

**Warning:** mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in "Path" on line xx

Comment: This is because mysqli_query($abfrage) is failing (and returning false because of that); in other words there is an error in your SQL statement. Unfortunately I can't tell what exactly is wrong since I don't know the schema of your database. PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues